# Java Error code null pointer at different class

Tags: java, exception

> The code still error, even though I have already fixed almost half the program
>   this initialized at main class:
>   [image]

Getting the below error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>     java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at Tugas7.No3.seqSearch(No3.java:72)
>     at Tugas7.No3Main.main(No3Main.java:27)

what are you expecting to get out?
I excepting the code when run can search the number

```
package Tugas7;
public class No3 {

    public int[] data;
    public int jumData,min,max;
;
    public int baris, kolom, posisiBar, posisiKol, posisi;

    public void No3(int[] data) {
        sort(data, 0, 8);
    }

    private void merge(int[] data, int left, int middle, int right) {
        int[] temp = new int[data.length];
        for (int i = left; i <= right; i++) {
            temp[i] = data[i];
        }
        int a = left;
        int b = middle + 1;
        int c = left;

        while (a <= middle && b <= right) {
            if (temp[a] <= temp[b]) {
                data[c] = temp[a];
                a++;
            } else {
                data[c] = temp[b];
                b++;
            }
            c++;
        }
        int s = middle - a;
        for (int i = 0; i <= s; i++) {
            data[c + i] = temp[a + i];
        }
    }

    private void sort(int data[], int left, int right) {
        if (left < right) {
            int middle = (left + right) / 2;
            sort(data, left, middle);
            sort(data, middle + 1, right);
            merge(data, left, middle, right);
        }
    }

    public void printArray(int arr[]) {
        int n = arr.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public int[] Searching(int[] Data, int jmlData) {
        this.jumData = 10;
        data = new int[jumData];
        for (int i = 0; i < jumData; i++) {
            data[i] = Data[i];
        }
        return data;
    }

    public int seqSearch(int cari) {
       this.posisi = -1;
        for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
            if (data[j] == cari) {
                posisi = j;
                break;
            }
        }
        return posisi;
    }

    public void TampilData() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(data[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void searchMax(int[] data) {
        min = data[0];
        max = data[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (data[i] < min) {
                min = data[i];
            } else if (data[i] > max) {
                max = data[i];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The data array in your `seqSearch` method seems not to be initialized when you are trying to acces element j. You need to make sure the array is initialized.

Comment: at main class i finish initialized

Comment: I'm sure you did, but the exception is thrown in the `seqSearch` method and the only thing there causing a `NullPointerException` could be the data array.